# Salesforce hide related list if empty

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning, page-layout, child-objects

I am working on an object which has 3 related lists. For some conditions only one could have data. The other two related lists are empty. Is it possible to hide a related list if there is no data to show.